# ¿Como obtener el penúltimo registro en un arreglo?

Tags: python, array, odoo, openerp

Tengo una función que busca un id & lo compara con otro, una vez hecho esto busca ese id en una lista, sin embargo, quiero obtener como resultado el penúltimo registro de esa lista & almacenarlo en el objeto `id_ultimo_costo`

A continuación les dejo la función:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('seller_ids')
def _costo_anterior(self):
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if self.default_code or self.default_code !='':
        product_search = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=',self.default_code)],limit = 1) 
        all_seller_ids = product_search.seller_ids.ids
        _logger.info('seller_ids: %s', all_seller_ids)

        if  all_seller_ids:
            id_ultimo_costo =  all_seller_ids[1]
            supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
            self.costo_anterior = supplier.price
            _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.costo_anterior)
        else:
            self.costo_anterior = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa indices relativos: -1 es el último elemento, -2 es el penúltimo, etc.

```
penultimo = lista[-2]
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!! Muchas gracias